# SSRS New Section per field value, with column headers

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I'd like to have a SSRS Report as below picture where there is a new section creation per column x value, and have new column headers each time

i.e. Team Column can be Team A, Team B, Team C. So a section per team, each with the column headers underneath.

I've tried row grouping on the Team field but it puts them horizontally :S

Any help would be great :) I'm sure its simple but i can't seem to phrase it in a way Google helps me

Thanks

[image]

This is how it looks following the directions in the first answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, need some cosmetics here.

Assuming your table looks like this:

[image]

- Add "Group Above".

[image]

- Merge the row that you add.

[image]

- Choose the column that holds the "teams" value (TEAM in my example), and delete the top row.

[image]

- Choose the group row (TEAM) and insert row - Group below, then 
  write the header for the columns below.
  [image]

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Benzi, really appreciate this. I would not have thought to delete the column names and then type them in.  With this case, lets say there were multiple rows for Team A and Team B, i'd like all of the Teams row under the one header, by following your instruction it has added a new header and column names for each row.

Comment: I added a new image into the Question to show how it looks after following your instruction.

Comment: Hmmm this doesn't change anything for me, i get the same results. I tried just following the first 3 bullet points to narrow down where i could be going wrong, but again i still get TEAM A and TEAM B numerous times. Could it be an issue with the datatype?

Comment: Are you able to show you row groups because when i follow your instructions my grouping does not look like yours in bullet point 4? I just have the details group

Comment: Hi, @Lee I added to my question a pic that shows how my table looks like. good luck